# Coldfusion CFC creation timeouts

Tags: windows, coldfusion, components, creation

After searching to no end, as well as countless hours of trial and error with different settings, I've come up completely empty on why my server is performing so slowly.

Here are the basics. I've switched hosting from a local server (CF8 running on ubuntu) to a better equipped hosting company (CF10 running on Windows Server 2008). Both servers ran Xeon processors. My old linux server ran on 8GB ram. Windows is running on 9GB. Both are running 64-bit. The problem I am having is on a very simple task: initial CFC creation.

I have a custom created CMS, that runs 2 sets of CFC (application and session scoped) for the general public, only application scope CFC's are created, and when a user logs into the site, additional session scoped CFC's are created (anywhere from 8 - 16 depending on the number of modules the site contains).

On the linux box this worked great, fast with no issues. However, since switching to the Windows server and CF10, the creation process has become dreadful.  When I go to log into a site, authentication is done, and the CFC's are created. When I first log into a site, this process can take anywhere from 15 - 50 seconds.  When I log out, the session scope variables are all killed. If I was to log in a 2nd time, within a short period of time, my login time runs about 1 - 5 seconds depending on server load.

My initial thinking is that it's a memory allocation issue, but I'm running out of ideas. I have some of the following specs

- JVM - 1.7.0_40
- JVM Heap Size 1280
- PermSize 256m
- Simultaneous request limit 100
- CFC request limit 60
- cfthread pool size 50
- trusted cache is currently off

I've set worker threads in IIS to have 5 per application. Each worker process runs at about 12,000k.

If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to debug without knowing more of the code details. Can you enable ColdFusion debugging for your ip and check the processing times for different parts of your page. This should at least give you an idea of where the time is being spent.

Comment: I experience no slowness anywhere on the site only during initial CFC creation, and only the first time they are created which leaves me to believe it's something to do with how it allocates memory to a specific application, when creating the sessions it would need extra memory space, but after that creating again would fit into the allocated memory that was already allocated, if that makes sense ..

Comment: Have you compared the Caching page in CF Administrator? I would compare those settings carefully.

Comment: session scoped cfcs?  That sounds scary.  The way browsers work these days, the less data you have in the session scope, the better.

Comment: items get added to the session scope for security, all the editing functions are kept on session scopes that are only created once a user successfully logs in. Even then, the only thing stored in the session CFC's is functions, no global variables that take up mountains of space. This still wouldn't resolve the initial creation issue.

Comment: @DanBracuk, what's the browser got to do with the session scope?

Comment: Can you create a portable repro case, including timing metrics, and post that code and your metrics. On the whole, CF10 craps all over CF8 on CFC operations.

Comment: alright, reproducing is part of the issue as i have 2 servers, linux running cf8 and windows running cf10, only the windows machine is giving me issues running the exact same code i was running on linux.

but, the breakdown is essentially this. go to a login screen, enter username and password. when submitted it calls an application scoped component for security functions. checks to make sure the IP address isn't on a block list, then checks the login info, if valid, gets a list of modules that user has access to. Then loops over that list to create the cfc's. each CFC has about 5 to 10k lines

Comment: Code looks like

<CFLOOP query="getModules">
     <CFSCRIPT>
          #Evaluate("session.POOL.cfc_#name# = createObject('component','#moduleLocation#components.editing.#name#').init()")#;
     </CFSCRIPT>
</CFLOOP>

each init call just returns "this"

Comment: Metrics at the time is "**
Max threads: 200 Current thread count: 10 Current thread busy: 9 Max processing time: 66574 Request count: 32 Error count: 0 Bytes received: 0 Bytes sent: 477940 Free memory: 868478128 Total memory: 1301938176 Active Sessions: 30 **" this is after a fresh server reboot

CPU is at 20 - 40%, ram is around 4 - 6GB used, with a total of 9 free

Comment: Don't describe the code. **Post the actual code**. Write the minimum code that demonstrates the issue, so we have something we can comparatively run (reading: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html). As I said, post a portable repro case. And before you do anything else, get that `evaluate()` out of your code. It's not needed.